# My Apple devices always seem to slow down over the years

Tags: iphone

It seems like every time I buy an Apple product the speed of it always slows down. I bought an iPod a year or two ago and the speed at which it launches apps and runs the apps have slowed down. Is there any way to fix this? Like buy an iPhone and it will never slow down?

Comment: Can you expand on this and explain what you've already tried to do to fix this? Otherwise you may get suggestions to do what you've already tried! Also, you need to provide more details: we have no idea what model iPod, what version of iOS it's running, how much space you still have on it, etc.

Comment: Without a specific device or a specific measure of slowness, this likely it too subjective to be open long term on the site. Let's put a hold on i case you have a specific so and specific measurement in mind.

Answer (score 4):

You have several options to fight against the slackening of your devices (or the perception of it):

- don't install apps (especially apps bloating over time because of feature updates)
- don't use faster and newer devices of the same kind (or better: the older your own devices get, ask friends or colleagues to lend to you their much older and slower devices more frequently and use them and you will happily return to your own "faster" device)
- get old faster than your devices (or reduce the perception of speediness or responsiveness artificially)
- take Zen lessons

Comment: Add to this clearing, or apps that do not clear the cache. An app can also leave large amounts of data in your clipboard without you knowing about it. That is until you to a copy/paste and see immediate improvement. The mail program on iPad is like this. The amount of space it takes grows even when you delete gigs worth of data.

Comment: Also not installing updates if possible

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what klanomath suggests, another option is to do a full backup, erase, and restore.

By this I mean do a full backup to iTunes on your computer. Once you've done this, go to your iPod and do the following:

- Tap on Settings
- Tap on General
- Swipe up
- Tap on Reset
- Tap on Erase All Content and Settings
- Enter your passcode to go through the process
- Reconnect your iPod to iTunes on your computer
- Opt to restore the backup you made earlier

This process should improve your iPod's responsiveness etc